# (Eclipse) Android force close

Tags: android, button

This is the java code and xml file for a program I am writing, and it force closes whenever i try to invoke the plusCalc button in-program. Could someone please tell me why?
Thank you!

Java file:

```
package org.example.knittingframe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;

public class KnittingFrame extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View plusCalc = findViewById(R.id.plus_calc_button);
    plusCalc.setOnClickListener(this);
    View exitbutton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
} 
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
     case R.id.plus_calc_button:
         startPlusCalc();
         break;
     case R.id.exit_button:
         finish();
         break;
     }
}

public void startPlusCalc() {
     Intent i = new Intent(this, PlusCalc.class);
     startActivity(i);
}

}
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/main_label"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:textSize="24.5sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus_calc_button"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/plusCalc_label"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post logcat stack error?

Comment: It looks like your opening <LinearLayout> tag is missing from the XML file.

Comment: I would guess it might be a problem of Layout in PlusCalc.class or you simply didn't register the PlusCalc Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml, please post the logcat stack trace to correctly tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without the stack trace it appears that the problem is with declaring the PlusCalc.class class in the App Manifest file, because as you say, the error only appears when you click on the PlusCalc button.

If this doesn't help please post the stack trace.